# Swift - UITableViewCell Access From Another UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift2

I am running into some challenges with Swift.

I have a UITableView with prototype cells.
There are 3 cells
The first two contains a textfield that the user fills.
The third one contains a submit button.

Very straightforward !

My problem is that the Submit button needs to be enabled only if both of the textfield contains text.

That would be easy if the page was not build with a Table view but it is built like that and the requirement are now changing and it leads to my issue.
It is a Security Question/Response page so since the first two cells are the same in term of layout, the TableView approach makes sense.

My issue is that I do not know how to access the Third cell button during the other cells actions.

Basically I have a delegate on TextDidChange in the Textfield cell, but I cannot access the button in the last cell to enable it.

I can easily have a prototype or delegate that will propagate the value or action to the ParentViewController, but that does not help me since I need to have access to the button in the Third cell.

What's the best approach here ??

Thank you for the help !

Comment: Please post your code.  Are these the only 3 cells that will ever be in the tableView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are many ways to do that, I will give you an example of one:

Idea:
Basically you need your model to maintain the state of the cells (In this case the textfields / button layout), and then every time that a textField is update you can check if it’s empty and update the model of the button cell to reflect that (you can call reloadRowsAtIndexPaths, every time that the textfields are update, in the case I'm assuming that the last cell), in the example to check which cell was edited I use the tag property. That's going to work with whatever length of Questions).

Here I enabled the button base on a property of the model. But you can also get the button cell using (but you also need to update the model, because if occurs a refresh on the view you will lose the control over enable/disable action when a cell reuse):

```
if let cellButton = self.tblSample.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: sampleData.count - 1, inSection: 0)) as? ButtonCellClass{

}
```

Example:
https://github.com/Abreu0101/TableViewButtonDisable

Comment: Perfect !!! I actually was starting of doing that !!! It works perfectly :) Thank you so much :)